# Range selection that changes depending on row number and column number set in 2 cells at the top of the worksheet

Tags: excel, variables, range, selection

I want to select a range that changes dependent on a row number entered into a specific cell.  This is so that I can run a macro to select data that varies in range size.

Example:  Cell A1 - i want to be able to set the row for the selection to go down to.
Cell A2 - I want to be able to set the column I want the selection to go over to or alternatively have a set column that doesn't change

This is so that when the amount of data changes I can just set the row number to select down to and the column to go across to, or alternatively have the column number staying the same

Comment: Sounds like you have a code attempt that you could share with us?

Comment: If I end up solving the problem I will definitely share as this could be a useful tip.